# Github PR template progress API

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request

Recently we've started using the github pull request templates to provide more info about the code being checked in.

Since there is a template one can see the progress, which is basically the number of fields filled in the PR template.

It is something like:

[image]

My question is, is there an API to analyze the same? Or is there a bot that does the same? Gives me the progress of the fields of the PR template?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the [`v3/pulls/reviews/` API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/reviews
```

That will list the reviews for a given PR (not PR *template* though, so you might have to create one artificially).

Comment: What do you mean by creating one artificially? Will I get some metadata or some response regarding the PR template in the API response?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava no, the API is for PR, not PR templates. You need to create a PR template first, for said template to be used, and for PR reviews to be monitored with the API I mention.